# Openshift - Wildcard routing to path

Tags: routes, openshift

How to use `Route` to redirect to a specific path using a wildcard. For ex., if I need to define a singe path which can redirect the redirect all my request that matches a given wildcard, to a path. How can that be done?

For ex.,  Can I define a router which routes all the request that starts with `mypath*`, of format //mypath*

As I [have gone through](https://trello.com/c/kAiVgvh9/373-3-make-cli-understand-wildcard-routes-ingress), the wildcard is supported for a subdomain, but there ain't seem to be a reference for path wildcard.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the wildcard patterns/rules you want to use so we can see them and run experiments to work out what is required.

Comment: You do know that so long as only matching a prefix, and not arbitrary regex/glob style matching, you can use path based routing. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#path-based-routes